# Executing an Illustrator batch action using Python

Tags: python, adobe, adobe-illustrator

Does anybody know how to execute an illustrator batch action using python??
In Python I have images moved into a folder after they are processed using PILLOW. Then there's an action in Illustrator called "Export" that I made that converts images into another proprietary file format for an Imposition system we use. I want to be able to call a batch action to be performed using the "Export" action. I'm assuming Win32com is they way to do it I just don't know what write in python to use certain actions.

`adobe_document = adobe_app."????"()`

I did try putting "Actions.Export" where I put the ????.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can make Illustrator the default application to open all jsx files.

And you can write a jsx script to run any Illustration action.

After that all you need is to execute the jsx file from your Python script with `os.system("your_script.jsx")`. It will run Illustrator which will start the script that will fire your action.